# How do I write a css-selector for text that is not inside any dom element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I need a css selector to print "grab me" without other siblings in java selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#demo")); // "You can't grab me without this"
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<span>You can't</span>
grab me
<span>without this</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason "grab me" isn't inside <span> tags?

Also, after adding the tags, try 
    #demo:nth-child(2)

Comment: Has any body stopped to explain to Nazmul Islam that all elements that are displayed to the user appear in the BODY tag of the document, and that therefore the BODY is the parent element, and in line with the Document Object Model you can go as far up as the root of the document which is the HTML tag

Comment: @Eric this is how webpage is built. i understand I can talk to developer to put it inside span or something but I wanted to see if there is a workaround

Comment: @DataCure Yes, I very much understand it's inside body, even it is inside a div in this case. But my original question is how do I write a css selector to get just "grab me" by ignoring other siblings.

Comment: @NazmulIslam Honestly, the easiest way is to just throw an opening and closing span tag around "grab me". However, if you HAVE to use it as it is, then you could make a CSS rule that sets the spans to display: none; prior to the alert being displayed... so that they are, for all intensive purposes, removed from the page. Then after the user clicks ok you can set it back to inline or whatever it was before.

Really there are a thousand ways to do this. Each way will be more complex than the previous. No need to reinvent the wheel in my opinion, but it seems like you're in a tough spot.